# Create new column to long data format if group have more than one factor level?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to subset and recreate a new column to my long format data based on the number of levels on each factors.

For example, site `a` can have either distance `b20` or `b5`, but site `b` and `c` have only single value for distance (`b20`).

If there are more factors, my new column `source` should hold value "unclear", if there is only one factor, use the `distance` value in according row.

```
# Dummy data frame
df<- data.frame(year = c(1,1,2,1,5,5,10),
                distance = c("b20", "b5", "b20", "b20", "PA", "b5", "PA"),
                site     = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e"))


    > df
  year distance site
1    1      b20    a  # `a` has more than 1 distances => source == unclear
2    1       b5    a
3    2      b20    b
4    1      b20    c
5    5       PA    d  # `d` has more than 1 distances => source == unclear
6    5       b5    d
7   10       PA    e
```

Desired output:

```
 > df
  year distance site source
1    1      b20    a unclear 
2    1       b5    a unclear
3    2      b20    b b20
4    1      b20    c b20
5    5       PA    d unclear
6    5       b5    d unclear
7   10       PA    e PA
```

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(distance) == 1)
`

Comment: @RonakShah, thank you for your answer, but I have substantially modified my question. Maybe you know how to solve this one as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a simple `ifelse` statement,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(site) %>% 
 mutate(source = ifelse(n_distinct(distance) == 1, as.character(distance[1]), 'unclear'))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 4
> # Groups:   site [5]
>    year distance site  source 
>   <dbl> <fct>    <fct> <chr>  
> 1     1 b20      a     unclear
> 2     1 b5       a     unclear
> 3     2 b20      b     b20    
> 4     1 b20      c     b20    
> 5     5 PA       d     unclear
> 6     5 b5       d     unclear
> 7    10 PA       e     PA
> ```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table` would be to first create a copy of the 'distance' column as 'source', get the row index (`.I`) where the length of unique 'distance' elements are not equal to 1 grouped by 'site' and assign (`:=`). the 'source' to 'unclear'

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, source := distance][, .I[uniqueN(distance) != 1], site]$V1
df[i1, source := 'unclear'][]
#  year distance site  source
#1:    1      b20    a unclear
#2:    1       b5    a unclear
#3:    2      b20    b     b20
#4:    1      b20    c     b20
#5:    5       PA    d unclear
#6:    5       b5    d unclear
#7:   10       PA    e      PA
```

#### data

```
df<- data.frame(year = c(1,1,2,1,5,5,10),
                distance = c("b20", "b5", "b20", "b20", "PA", "b5", "PA"),
                site     = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e"), 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```